# Want to show input field data in a div on run time

Tags: jquery

Hello Friends i am new in development its my 1st project and i want to know how to show input field data in a div on run time just like in stackoverflow questions section, and please suggest me the best framework for this i just know jQuery that's why i want to develop this in JQuery. please help me.

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname">

    <div>Want to show input text here on run time</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>div{display:none;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname">

        <div>Want to show input text here on run time</div>
    </body>
    <script>
         // Put your event handler here on which you want to show this div
         getElementsByTagName("div").css("display", "block");
    </script>
 </html>
```